# MS access sum results between two dates as text box in form

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I issue following query in SQL and works fine

```
SELECT SUM(goudOpkoop.winst) 
FROM goudOpkoop 
WHERE goudOpkoop.date
BETWEEN '2015-1-10' AND '2015-1-22'
```

I would like to have the results in a Form in *Textbox 3* (name Text183) when last of two dates, one in *Textbox 1* (name Text179) and other in textbox 2 (name Text181) have been picked.

I think I would need to use `AfterUpdate` code builder for *Textbox 2* and issue there the query to eventually show results in *Textbox 3*.
I have already linked with SQL server.

> Information: ODBC;DSN=Essence Test;;TABLE=goudOpkoop

In me not being a professional in VBA I have no clue how to get this working.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but should do the trick slightly, unless I made a typo.

Change the format of your 2 dates textboxes in "Short Date", that way you will have a calendar picker and you will ensure that your date have a correct format

Create this sub in your form module :

```
Private Sub CheckSUM()

    Dim RST As Recordset
    Dim SQL As String

    ' Reset the result textbox
    Text183.value = ""

    ' If your 2 date textboxes are not populated, cancel
    If Text179.Value = "" or Text181.Value = "" Then Exit Sub

    ' Prepare the query, with proper formating of the dates
    SQL = " SELECT SUM(goudOpkoop.winst) AS mySum " & _
          " FROM goudOpkoop " & _
          " WHERE goudOpkoop.Date " & _
          "     BETWEEN '" & Format(Text179.Value, "YYYY-MM-DD") & "' " & _
          "         AND '" & Format(text181.Value, "YYYY-MM-DD") & "'"

    ' Execute the query
    Set RST = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL)

    ' If the query is valid and returned something, we recuperate the value
    If Not RST.BOF Then
        Text183.Value = RST!mySum
    End If

    ' Cleaning
    RST.Close
    Set RST = Nothing

End Sub
```

Then, for your 2 dates textboxes, create an *afterupdate* event and call the previous sub in them:

```
Private Sub Text179_AfterUpdate()
    CheckSUM
End Sub

Private Sub Text181_AfterUpdate()
    CheckSUM
End Sub
```

Comment: The date delimiter in MS Access is #. Why not just use DSum?

Comment: Because I am a multi-environement programmer and that I never use all those ms-access-only features. A pure recordset method is valid through all office and most .NET products, and IMHO it is much better and simpler to adopt a standarized way of working accross multiple environments.
You might be correct for the dates delimiter ##, but maybe not. his table is external and whe don't know which RDBMS it is and how its date fields are declared. If he notifes an issue I'll adapt accordingly

Comment: Tag says access-vba :)

Comment: And you consider my approach not Access-VBA? are you kidding me ? :)